# Use immutable js to set reducer state to returned array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I have a simple reducer example:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'
import {
  REQUEST_SUCCESS
} from './constants'

const initialState = fromJS({
  badges: []
})

function badgesReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set('badges', action.payload.badges || [])
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default badgesReducer
```

Idea here is to set badges equal to array returned by api response that is within `action.payload.badges` however I believe I am doing something wrong as I get following error returned:

> warning.js:44 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `badges` of type
>   `object` supplied to `Badges`, expected `array`

Comment: An immutable object is an 'Object', just change the propType in your component

Comment: @Teo is there any way to return it as array?

Comment: Are you positive `action.payload.badges` is an array? What do you have it set as in your `proptypes`? What does `this.props.badges` look like when you log it out in the component using it and throwing that error? Where are you doing your `.toJs()`?

Comment: @ajmajmajma action.payload.badges definetely returns array of objects. propTypes of badges are set to array. not sure about `toJs` question, but I believe you reffer to me selecting badges from the state? I do that through selectors like myState.get('transactions')

Comment: I believe what Teo is saying above is your prop of badges might still be in immutable format (even though you set it as an array in the reducers), which would make it an object until you either `.toJS()` it or `immutableObj.get('badges')`. It is hard to say without seeing how you are handling all of this.

Comment: @ajmajmajma turns out that for some reason react runs this 2 times returning transactions as <List> the first time and as array the second.

Comment: You should drop your code in a fiddle or something if you want help with this, the reducer alone is not going to show the problem.

Comment: It's because you're doing a fromJS on initalState which is doing a deep mutation of the object into an immutable, turning the badges key into an Immutable object. Then when your request is done and you actually receive  badges as an array you're setting it as an Array. Deadfish answer should help you if you want to stick with immutable objects everywhere if not, just change the fromJS on initialState to Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because react is expecting an array but you're returning an Immutable.List. And React renders the component twice because the first render happens with reducer initialState and then the second render is caused due to props change (after the dispatched action).

Your props are inconsistent since you are passing Immutable.List in initialState & array in `REQUEST_SUCCESS` action.

If you want to stick with Immutable.js everywhere, then declare propTypes like this.

#### Component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { List } from 'immutable'

Component.propTypes = {
  badges: PropTypes.instanceOf(List)
}
```

#### Reducer

```
import { fromJS, List } from 'immutable'

function badgesReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set('badges', fromJS(action.payload.badges) || List())
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And if you want to always pass an array to the component, remove fromJS from the initialState declaration